# Difficulties getting regex parsing local weather information inside RSS with ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, rss, expression, cdata

I am using a website agent to get data from our local oceanographic institute.
The feed is available here: http://www.geomar.de/service/wetter/feed/

Inside the feed is a tag which holds the weather sensors content with html markup:
e.g. Lufttemperatur = air temperature
Wassertemperature = water temperature
etc.

I am trying to get the values for each station ( e.g. Lufttemperatur for station Institut , Wassertemperatur for station Institute etc)
I was helped with a regex on rubular.com: http://rubular.com/r/INYCQF5Y6H

On rubular I get a valid response but in my ruby I get an empty []

I am happy for any help
thanks

Comment: You should really be using an XML parsing library instead of regex.

Comment: The website Agent can also parse xml but I cannot parse the data inside the CDATA ... because of that I switch to text and regex.
any ideas?

Comment: No need to use technology to know the weather in Kiel, It's always cold.

Comment: yes :) you are right but wind speed is nice to know for surfing !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was at the point to suggest you to use nokogiri that is an excellent xml parser, but after a look at the xml code I realised that the data you are looking for are not structured at all with xml tags. This is the reason why, for this specific page, a basic text research is more appropriate:

You can obtain all the key/value with this pattern:

```
([^:\s<>][^:><]+): ([^<]+)
```

[online demo](http://rubular.com/r/Yh3nrJcMsH)

obviously, you will need to deal with html entities like `&deg;` after.

Comment: @othreed: note that you can be more precise like this: http://rubular.com/r/6CqI0bJrRP

Comment: thank you so much for the help. This is my first time posting here :)
I am studying your code and experimenting.
Did my first regex just 2 days ago :)

Comment: @othreed: rubular is a good tool to experiment regexes for ruby, but you can get more informations about a pattern using regex101.com